# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

I recently moved and set up my system with a new wifi router. Since then, my Ubuntu randomly loses wifi every 5-10 minutes. I have to turn off the wifi setting on my computer and turn it back on to regain internet. Sometimes the wifi will stop and the network history will show full usage and my computer will freeze, requiring a restart. I upgraded to a comcast wifi 6 router. My wifi card is a Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a). Does anyone know how to fix this?