# Wifi card on ubuntu frequently keeps dropping connection/

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless, kernel

for a few weeks my wifi card keeps dropping connection with router once or two for an hour, it usually  last for few minutes and reconnect. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Don't know if it matters, I'm using bluetooth headphones but I used them before while my network worked perfectly. Wifi on windows and on my smartphone works well.

uname:

```
Linux PC***** 5.4.0-105-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 7 18:49:24 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lshw -class network:

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 10
   serial: 98:fa:9b:3a:fc:57
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
   resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:a1304000-a1304fff memory:a1300000-a1303fff

 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless-AC 9260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlp5s0
   version: 29
   serial: 58:a0:23:83:ac:7a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-105-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:a1200000-a1203fff
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.