# wifi network connection slow and disconnecting randomly in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I am complete beginner not much knowledge about Linux it would nice if anyone would help i am trying to fix it for long. This is my first post if there are any mistakes please forgive me.Sorry for such a long post and Thank You.

**System Information**

```
uname -a
Linux 5.13.0-40-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 09:38:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

i don't know will it matter or not but my laptop uses uefi firmware.

```
neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               samarth@samarth-HP-Laptop-15s-dr1xxx 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: HP Laptop 15s-dr1xxx 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.13.0-40-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 23 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2397 (dpkg), 9 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: LoginIcons [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i5-10210U (8) @ 4.200GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX130 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 2499MiB / 7754MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

**Network Device Details**

```
sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 84:2a:fd:cd:34:45
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.17.0-051700-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b4304000-b4304fff memory:b4300000-b4303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 28:cd:c4:cc:8a:a3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.17.0-051700-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:141 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4200000-b420ffff
```

I have tried the following :-

1. I have changed the powersave mode like this : -

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

2. Tried by reading forums but after this disconnecting get reduced , but speed is still slow.

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/&usbcore.autosuspend=-1 /' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
sudo systemctl reboot
```

**Edited**
3.`sudo ip link set devName mtu 1492` solved the connection breaking issue for me.My default mtu is 1500 and mtu in router config is 1480 is it not a problem? But Network is still sometime slow.

Errors i found after 3rd are :-

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager
sup-iface[0x563452621110,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
```

reason -4 means NM_DEVICE_STATE_REASON_CONFIG_FAILED now what would be the fix?
and some errors on bootup

```
ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
```

Comment: You seem to be on the dangerous path to a couple of Well-known Errors: Applying a "solution" before diagnosing the problem, AND blindly applying "solutions from the 'Net" without understanding them, or what they do. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for quick response. I have read the journalctl -f whenever i encounter any problem with my wifi , but i was unable to understand anything.Errors on booting are `ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist ` 
`Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate ` Most frequent issue which i found is `sup-iface[0x55c25d436910,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4) `for this problem i have already read the forum which suggests me to do 2nd point which i have done.Sorry If i am immature here.

Comment: One More error not very recurring `dns-sd-resolved[a91bad4d0e246da6]: send-updates failed to update systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 4 not known`.read the forums suggested to make tmp directory in /var and saying that occurs due to absence of it but it was already there in my case.

Comment: Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723

Comment: @chili555 Thanks a lot ig that was the problem but i will see it for one day as the problem occurs sometimes, `ip link` output mtu as 1500 for wireless connection , but my router config mtu is 1480 is it a problem. After using the suggested command everything looks fine but i will wait for 1 day to be confirmed.Thanks a lot @chili555

Comment: @waltinator as suggested by chili555 i have changed the mtu it doesn't disconnects , but if jyou ust clarify my last comment that would be nice and speed is still very low.Thanks to You Both.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: Okay I am very sorry.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I Updated DKMS from software and updates (gui),which solved my issue ,as there is no problem now for a week and no errors in journalctl too.
Now i am using

```
dkms -V
dkms:2.8
```

and

```
dkms status
nvidia, 470.103.01, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.32, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.32, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
```