# WiFi regularly disconnects on new install of Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 (Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter)

Tags: wireless, atheros

I am having an issue on a completely new install of Ubuntu budgie 22.04, wifi regularly and seemingly randomly disconnects or drops significantly in speed. The behaviour is weird though as it seems to happen every time I try to run a speedtest on speedtest.net, the ping section runs fine then the down speed test starts fine before dipping to a few mbps then the test fails entirely at the start of the up speed test. Also none of these issues occur on the windows install dual booted with ubuntu on this pc so its not an issue with wifi range or the router.

I have tried a few other fixes I found from on posts of a similar issue however none have worked:

**Disabling wifi powersave:**
I have edited `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and set `wifi.powersave = 2`

**Disabling hardware encryption:** I also disabled hardware encryption with the following command: `echo "options ath5k nohwcrypt=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/99-local.conf`

I have also disabled Ipv6 and forced connection to the 5ghz band of my wifi (both 2.6ghz and 5ghz has the same SSID and unfortunately this is something I cannot change).

**Here is some more info about the hardware:**

**iwconfig:**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VM6707828"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 40:0D:10:E8:AC:67   
          Bit Rate=324 Mb/s   Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:22   Missed beacon:0
```

**lspci | grep -i wireless:**

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions on how to fix the issue.

**Logs from when it drops out:**

```
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.3798] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.4860] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.4860] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.4960] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.4960] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.4961] device (wlp3s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5149] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5149] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5149] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed no lease
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5150] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5153] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5153] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5444] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:22:48 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771368.5446] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:22:50 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771370.6177] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.19
May 05 18:22:54 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771374.8576] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="9fae5549-16d4-4bde-9dc2-c00f4749ddef" name="VM6707828" args="802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg,ipv6.meth>
May 05 18:23:46 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771426.9030] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:23:46 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771426.9030] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:23:46 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771426.9757] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:23:46 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771426.9757] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:23:47 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771427.0563] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:23:47 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771427.0563] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:23:47 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771427.4158] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
May 05 18:23:47 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771427.9197] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:23:47 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771427.9198] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:23:50 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771430.1147] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 05 18:23:50 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771430.1148] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <warn>  [1651771441.8732] device (wlp3s0): link timed out.
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771441.8735] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771441.8736] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <warn>  [1651771441.8739] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'VM6707828'
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771441.8743] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771441.8973] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771441.8973] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:24:01 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771441.8973] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed no lease
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3153] policy: auto-activating connection 'VM6707828' (9fae5549-16d4-4bde-9dc2-c00f4749ddef)
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3157] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'VM6707828' (9fae5549-16d4-4bde-9dc2-c00f4749ddef)
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3158] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3159] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3161] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3162] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'VM6707828' has security, but secrets are required.
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3163] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3164] sup-iface[9870afce4bbba1ac,0,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3169] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3171] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3173] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'VM6707828' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3173] Config: added 'ssid' value 'VM6707828'
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3173] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3173] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3173] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3173] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3376] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3376] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3394] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3394] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3500] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3500] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3638] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3639] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3948] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3949] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "VM6707828"
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3949] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3950] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.3952] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5222] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.19
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5233] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5259] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5260] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5262] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5265] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5266] policy: set 'VM6707828' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5270] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 05 18:24:04 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771444.5272] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
May 05 18:25:11 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771511.3357] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="9fae5549-16d4-4bde-9dc2-c00f4749ddef" name="VM6707828" args="connection.timestamp,802-11-wireless.bssid" pid=3049 uid=1000 >
May 05 18:25:29 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771529.8948] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:25:29 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771529.8949] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:25:29 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771529.8949] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 05 18:25:29 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771529.9685] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:25:29 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771529.9686] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 18:25:30 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771530.0527] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:25:30 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771530.0527] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 05 18:25:30 matthew-MS-7A45 NetworkManager[755]: <info>  [1651771530.3999] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
```

Comment: Are you certain that your driver is ath5k? Maybe ath9k? Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "both 2.6ghz and 5ghz has the same SSID and unfortunately this is something I cannot change" I am confident that this is a big part of the issue. Please try binding to the MAC address of the 5 gHz band like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617

Comment: @chili555 Thank you very much for the reply, I tried your troubleshooting steps however they did not seem to help. I am not sure if it should be ath5k or ath9k is there a way to check? Also when I tried to run: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` it returned: `wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.`

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I doubt that your wireless interface is wlan0. Please try: `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: Thank you for the responses, chili555 I added the BSSID of the 5ghz channel however it did not seem to work. waltinator I had a look at the linked thread and nothing on it has helped, I will add logs from around the time it fails during the speedtest to bottom of the post as I can consistently get it to drop out.

Comment: Update: I managed to fix the network issues by updating the kernel, following one a guide linked in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723 I was hesitant to do this but nothing else worked, however now my display driver is broken so I guess I need to fix that now.