# Network connection extremely slow in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking

**Please understand the problem before blindly flagging this question as a duplicate**

I installed Ubuntu a few months ago and network connection speed was at full bandwidth. However, I have been experiencing very strange network speed drops **recently**.

---

#### Problem Description

Let's say network's bandwith is 20Mb/s. When I first boot up the computer, network is at full bandwidth. After a few minutes of usage, the network speed starts to decrease gradually until it reaches < 0.5Mb/s... Also the decrease is not constant, but the speed keeps spiking and falling back again.

**Some weird things I noticed**

- The network speed doesn't start decreasing at a fixed moment nor for a fixed period of time.
- If I turn Wifi Off and On, network speed gets better a little bit (not full bandwidth) then it continues to decrease again after a few minutes.

**Some assumptions based on the problem description**

- My hardware is not damaged because I can dual boot with windows where network speed is perfect
- The issue is most likely caused by a faulty program or misconfiguration (probably with network adapter since the problem doesnt occur with usb connection) because I was not experiencing this issue before on the same machine and on the same ubuntu version.

**HOWEVER**
I could not investigate more in the issue. It seems too vague and weird that I didn't know where to start troubleshooting.
Feel free to ask me for any  logs.

---

Some logs
`sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`

```
May 05 21:08:10 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <warn>  [1651781290.6156] sup-iface[0x562aba313a00,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
May 05 21:08:10 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <info>  [1651781290.6443] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnect>
May 05 21:08:11 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <info>  [1651781291.2362] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 05 21:08:15 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <info>  [1651781295.7832] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticat>
May 05 21:08:15 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <info>  [1651781295.7976] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> assoc>
May 05 21:08:15 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <info>  [1651781295.8087] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associat>
May 05 21:08:15 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <info>  [1651781295.8187] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way han>
May 05 21:08:15 LAPTOP-HP NetworkManager[14226]: <info>  [1651781295.8714] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> comp>
```

These logs are gettings repeated every 1~2 minutes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping)

Comment: No, it says the problem is only related to wifi and network card. My problem happens with all sorts of connections

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator please see my edit

Comment: May we see the same journalctl with ethernet, please? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't have a cable rn, would you like with usb ? Sorry @chili555

Comment: Your question clearly says: "Same issue occurs with all types of netork connection: wifi, usb, *ethernet cable*..." Would you care to amend it? Then show the journalctl with USB.

Comment: Oh, it actually works with usb. @chili555