# Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i WiFi Very Slow Connections on Ubuntu 20.04, also through the cable, known solutions do not work

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, router

I know it's a known and very common issue.

I had no problems with WiFi, but at some point my internet connection stopped working or it works very slowly.

The same is, when I connect the router with the laptop with a cable.
It is strange that I have such a problem with only one router at home.
When I connect to some other network, e.g. in the office or I'll make a HotSpot from my cell phone, it works quite normally.
Also at home, I only have a problem with the Ubuntu laptop, all other devices work normally.

I have tried to solve this issue myself by following all the recommended solution from the forum, unfortunately none of them worked.

It is very frustrating when you try to work.
I will be grateful for any hints what else I can do.

**link to the my logs with details:**
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6pG47Hfdq6/

Comment: The fact that you don't experience the problem when connecting to other networks tells you that the problem is with the network, not the OS.  Perhaps you need to use different settings to connect to this particular network?

Comment: I tried to change some network settings. 
Maybe you have some tips where i should look for.

Comment: Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem turned out to be with the docker and unused containers.
Docker created a network with the same IP address range as the router.
I have removed all unused containers and now everything works fine.

Thank you all for your advice and support.