# Ubuntu 22.04 Wifi speed is only half of mac os at most

Tags: wireless

It is a perfect hackintosh box. The wifi speed is about 800Mbps in Mac OS X. The wifi card is BCM943602CS.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04, the problem is that the wifi speed is not stable, the speed is about 1xx Mbps to 3xx Mbps.
I have googled to find the solution. What I have tried:

- Turn off power management: it did work, the speed increased somehow.
- Install firmware-b43-installer: no difference.

#### lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

> 05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom
> Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba]
> (rev 01)
> Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
> [106b:0133]
> Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
> Kernel modules: brcmfmac

#### And I checked the boot log, there is no difference between with or without installation of firmware-b43-installer.

#### sudo dmesg | grep brcm

> usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
> brcmfmac 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
> brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/1
> brcmfmac 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Acidanthera-iMac17,1.bin failed with error -2
> brcmfmac 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Acidanthera-iMac17,1.txt failed with error -2
> brcmfmac 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
> brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/1
> brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
> brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/1 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
> brcmfmac 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
> ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52

Comment: Are you connecting with WPA2 or WPA3?

Comment: Yes, it is WPA2. The same as in Mac OS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I have pasted the results.

Comment: How do you measure speed?

Comment: Copying the same file from ssd to a NAS directly connected to wifi router. And using speedtest.com to test internet speed.

Comment: `firmware-b43-installer` is totally unrelated.

Comment: It is better to post output of `dmesg | grep brcm` and please format output with `{}`

Comment: Sure, updated using dmesg | grep brcm

Comment: I don't think anything can be done here. The in-tree driver for the device is not perfect. Maybe install another wireless card.

Comment: Anyway, thinks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping)

Comment: same here, it's now 2022 and it's now ubuntu 22.10, still no obvious solution online.