# Slow and choppy internet connection

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, internet, 22.04, ath9k

I have recently upgraded by Kubuntu desktop to 22.04LTS version.
Everything is working fine except my internet over any WiFi connection is performing awefully dodgy. It works but very inconsistently. Slow speed, frequent drops in connection.

I have windows installed as dual boot. Internet is working fine there. Same I tested on other devices.

I tried reinstalling Kubuntu. Still I am getting same issue.
My laptop uses ath9k driver.

Please help!

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth?

Comment: yes I am using bluetooth. Is it causing issue?

Comment: BT and 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi is a problem. You can try a fix, I will write an answer.

Comment: Hi, It again started giving same issue today. Internet speeds drop to 0 suddenly. I have disabled Bluetooth but no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve BT and Wi-FI coexistence by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf <<< "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1"
```

Reboot and check.

To revert the setting, run

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did this also followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping . Now I can see normal speeds on speedtest.

Comment: Hi, It again started giving same issue today. Internet speeds drop to 0 suddenly. I have disabled Bluetooth but no difference.

Comment: There may be lots of reasons. Most likely your neighbors are using the same frequency, etc.

Comment: but this did not happen on previous version of Kubuntu. Do I need to rollback? or any other way I could solve this?