# 22.04 - sudo add-apt-repository times out

Tags: apt, add-apt-repository

Long story short, I have a 100% fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, and I can't seem to get add-apt-repository working without running it through a VPN. I can access the internet via browsers, Discord, and Ubuntu Software just fine. The same thing happened with this computer on 20.04, and eventually even the GUI updater that pops up when you boot up quit working after a few months so I figured I'd just wipe the drive and install the latest. I've run Ubuntu before on a different computer on this network no problem (its just a home network, no firewalls or anything), so I don't think its that.

My wifi card is the Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter, and the LAN is RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

It basically just sits for a few minutes, then I get `TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out` in the terminal and an "apt-get update has stopped working" pop-up with the option to send an error report to Ubuntu/Canonical.

Any input on what the issue might be would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you write the commands that you have run so that anyone can check how it works, so that someone can reproduce your problem?

Comment: And, as always for such cases, you should try a different server. That it works over a VPN but times out without suggests some ISP level problem.

Comment: What's your WIFI MTU? `ip link` will tell you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. After trying a few things, I came upon this [ubuntu forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474534) where some problems with the ipv6 routing are described. I turned off ipv6, rebooted and was able to add the repository. Sometime later, I activated ipv6 again.

If you have a working internet connection but

```
ping launchpad.net
```

doesn't return a proper response, the issue is likely the same and this fix may solve it.