# My internet is so slow(30kb/s)

Tags: internet

i just installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS for the first time, i conected to my wifi network and it's very slow, but then i conected to my phone hotspot and it was completly fine, then i conected via usb tethering from my phone via the same wifi network it was also fine.
I searched a lot, but i can't find anything.
can anyone help me?
[image: lspci]

Comment: - Go To W-FI Settings,  
Your Currently connected Wi-Fi /Access Point Name will be shown.  

- Click on the "settings" icon on the right side of it.  
Details of the connected Wi-Fi are shown.  

- Check the **DNS** IP being used. Is it the same as the **Default Route** IP?

Comment: Use `ip link` to see your WiFi MTU. If it's  1500 see my answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723 . Your MTU should be 1492 for WiFi.

Comment: I have 3 mtu values, two of them are 1500, and one of them is 65536

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I did sir, i hope you find something. @Pilot6

Comment: Yes, DNS IP is the same as default route. @ByronTaaka

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: I don't understand what should I do, I'm new to this, would you explain more.@Pilot6

Comment: @MuhammadAlaa-Eldin instead of an image copy and paste text into the question That way people searching for lspci will find this and people wanting to copy your command can also do that. This site is for all not just the peiople that ask questions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you delete the wifi connection, then re-connect.

```
nmcli connection delete <CONNECTION-NAME>
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

nmcli supports tab completion. You can find the connection to be deleted by pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd>

Then simply re-connect from the UI as you normally would.