# Ubuntu 22.04 has exremely slow wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

I recently faced this problem with my wireless home network. From wifi speed tests on other devices, I expect to get 6Mb/s, while on my laptop with 22.04 (Linux 5.15.0-40-generic) the speed ranges from 100kb/s to 1Mb/s at best. I can't test on ethernet at the moment, and I am always close to the router.
I would expect to get the same speed I see on other devices, and that my provider guarantees I do have at the moment.

I tried changing the PC power settings to maximal performance, but I observed no improvement. I also spent a couple of weekends trying some solutions reported here and elsewhere, excluding the complex ones like kernel updates. However, nothing worked.

I also noticed that on dual-booted Windows install on the same PC I get a better connection (maybe not a hardware issue?). Oddly enough, when I connect with Ubuntu 22.04 to the very same provider with wifi in my student house elsewhere, everything works smoothly. I tried to change the router, and still no improvement. Also, this problem seems to have emerged in U22, as I didn't notice this in 20!

Maybe someone can suggest the possible culprit? I am clueless!

EDIT: I might have found the problem, and it's weird. When multiple USB/USB-C/HDMI adapters are in use, at some point the wifi speed drops. Oddly, if I keep the lid of the laptop open, the problem is mitigated. Maybe there could be a better strategy to address this, but for the moment it works.

Below is the information on my system.

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 30
       serial: 18:56:80:68:f1:32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic firmware=46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a4414000-a4417fff


susb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 2.4GHz Wireless rechargeable vertical mouse [More&Better]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:009b Synaptics, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:9510 Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2109:0100 VIA Labs, Inc. USB 2.0 BILLBOARD           
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 14cd:8601 Super Top 4-Port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. VL813 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
spci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 30)
00:19.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc6 (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN500 / PC SN520 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
```

```
ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enx4865ee146e8d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:65:ee:14:6e:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:56:80:68:f1:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
4: gpd0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:b7:35:d1:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping)

Comment: @waltinator thank you, but unfortunately, that solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Read my answer (the checked one). I see that your MTU is 1500. My answer explains why this is wrong for WiFi, how to detect and how to fix. [Edit] your question and explain "doesn't work".

Comment: Thank you @waltinator, sorry I thought you were referring to the accepted answer and not yours. 

I will try your solution ASAP (it could take some time as I am elsewhere), and I edited the question with the output of `ip link`. I will set the MTU to 1492 and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried removing only the mouse dongle.  It might be wireless interference from it or the mouse, which depends on the different routers' choice of channel, and which might also be shielded by the lid position.  Trying a different USB socket for it might help too.

Comment: That is exactly what I did; thank you! It was so hard to troubleshoot this issue

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. After trying lots of suggestions on different sites, one that worked for me:-

Go into the Wifi setting and disable IPv6(The default is automatic).

As my router was automatically switching from IPv4 to IPv6 & Ipv6 was causing problems in my scenario.

Comment: Lifesaver! I bought a whole new adapter thinking my tiny one couldn't hack it because of the range.  This was it!  I was able to get great download speeds once connection was established, but connecting was really tough.  Now I know it wasn't the adapter, but rather the ipv4 issue.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I finally pinned down this as a problem with using HDMI and USB-C simultaneously. My machine couldn't handle it. I solved it using a USB-C adapter with HDMI and every other port I needed. Troubleshooting this was hell.

In my case, the issue was pretty unpredictable. It had to do with how many USB ports I was using. I am not sure how I got there, but having multiple stuff attached to the laptop (mouse dongle, keyboard, USB-C adapter, etc.) was somehow draining too much power, even when plugged in. I resolved to remove anything that was not strictly necessary, and it worked again as expected.