# How to troubleshoot unstable wireless after updating to 22.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, mediatek

I'm not sure exactly which update did me in, but wifi is super spotty now--it'll work for a bit then randomly disconnect. I don't have this problem when I boot into Windows, but it's been happening in Ubuntu (and Mint). I also tried booting into different kernels using the advanced options, but neither 5.15.25, 5.15.39 or 5.15.40 worked.

Generally it works after booting for a few mins, then stops (but wireless icon stays the same), and eventually the wireless icon shows a question mark. At that point all bets are off.

Here's the output of the ubuntu wireless info: https://pastebin.com/bYKfJFdt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping)

Comment: I tried a few things in these instructions but no luck. It was easier to install Manjaro =p