# RTL8723AE PCIe wireless network adapter fresh install issue

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop on my Clevo laptop.

`lspci` tells me the wireless networking card is:RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.

This laptop only has access to the internet via an open wifi network.

During the installation (I don't remember the exact wording, but) I indicated I wanted the non-free drivers installed.

The Ubuntu installation seems to know there is a wireless card there, but when I click on 'Select Network' I just get a 'No Networks' message. (My open network is visible to every operating system other than various linux distributions I have tried over the last couple of days!)

However when I select Wi-Fi Settings > Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Networks, then click the Connection 'New...' drop down menu, my open home network appears there. When I click connect I just get the turning logo for a while then nothing.

I assume I have some sort of driver issue.

I have tried installing firmware-iwlwifi_20210315-3_all.deb, and firmware-realtek_20190114-2_all.deb amongst many other things and now need a fresh pair of eyes.

```
@ron-370ST:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:0726]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
Kernel modules: rtl8723ae
ron@ron-370ST:~$ sudo dmesg | grep rtl8723ae
[sudo] password for ron: 
[    3.954194] rtl8723ae 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.971663] rtl8723ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
[    3.992840] rtl8723ae 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
ron@ron370ST:~$ sudo dmesg | grep wlp
[sudo] password for ron: 
[    3.992840] rtl8723ae 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Partial results of `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` :

```
[sudo] password for ronf: 
[    3.992840] rtl8723ae 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Network.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST avahi-daemon[713]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.7796] NetworkManager (version 1.36.4) is starting... (for the first time)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.7796] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.7868] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.7943] manager[0x55579a9a4040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.7943] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9184] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9184] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "ron-370ST"
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9288] dns-mgr[0x55579a97f2a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9305] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver rtl8723ae)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9307] manager[0x55579a9a4040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9307] manager[0x55579a9a4040]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9553] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9593] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9760] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9939] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9949] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9953] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9954] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9954] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST dbus-daemon[717]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=719 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9966] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9966] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9967] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9968] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9986] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jul  1 18:00:39 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9986] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694839.9990] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.0001] manager: (enp4s0f2): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.0019] settings: (enp4s0f2): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.0019] device (enp4s0f2): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.2148] device (wlp3s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.2154] manager: (wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.2160] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6197] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6239] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6826] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6827] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp3s0 created
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6829] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6832] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6836] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:00:40 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694840.6841] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:00:46 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694846.2146] manager: startup complete
Jul  1 18:00:46 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Finished Network Manager Wait Online.
Jul  1 18:00:46 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jul  1 18:00:47 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694847.8826] agent-manager: agent[4c241bfb9ce583a7,:1.49/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Jul  1 18:00:50 ron-370ST systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.7892] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' (a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706)
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.7910] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706" name="MyOpenNetwork Open" pid=2165 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8009] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8053] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8147] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8213] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8221] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyOpenNetwork Open'
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8223] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8225] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jul  1 18:02:36 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694956.8225] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Jul  1 18:02:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694957.2702] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:02:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694957.2708] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <warn>  [1656694982.2243] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694982.2244] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694982.2247] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <warn>  [1656694982.2248] device (wlp3s0): wifi-scan: active scanning for networks due to profiles with wifi.hidden=yes. This makes you trackable
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <warn>  [1656694982.2250] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open'
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694982.2254] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694982.2364] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:03:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[719]: <info>  [1656694982.2364] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Network.
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696019.3579] NetworkManager (version 1.36.4) is starting... (for the first time)
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696019.3585] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696019.3671] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST avahi-daemon[564]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696019.3748] manager[0x5582409b8040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696019.3748] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jul  1 18:20:19 ron-370ST dbus-daemon[568]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=570 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9653] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9653] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "ron-370ST"
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9661] dns-mgr[0x5582409952a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9673] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver rtl8723ae)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9674] manager[0x5582409b8040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9674] manager[0x5582409b8040]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9701] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9713] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9729] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9742] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9748] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9751] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9751] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9752] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST dbus-daemon[568]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=570 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9763] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9763] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9763] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9765] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9788] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9788] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9791] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9801] manager: (enp4s0f2): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9811] settings: (enp4s0f2): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696021.9812] device (enp4s0f2): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul  1 18:20:21 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.1939] device (wlp3s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.1952] manager: (wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.1955] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.5948] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.5992] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.6667] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.6668] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp3s0 created
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.6671] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.6674] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.6678] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <warn>  [1656696022.6684] device (wlp3s0): wifi-scan: active scanning for networks due to profiles with wifi.hidden=yes. This makes you trackable
Jul  1 18:20:22 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696022.6685] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:20:28 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696028.1943] manager: startup complete
Jul  1 18:20:28 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Finished Network Manager Wait Online.
Jul  1 18:20:28 ron-370ST systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jul  1 18:20:29 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696029.4620] agent-manager: agent[fc0f95d4a9d0321c,:1.47/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Jul  1 18:20:32 ron-370ST systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5267] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' (a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706)
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5269] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706" name="MyOpenNetwork Open" pid=2091 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5270] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5272] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5276] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5279] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5280] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyOpenNetwork Open'
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5280] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5280] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.5280] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.9312] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:23:23 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696203.9312] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:23:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <warn>  [1656696229.2240] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul  1 18:23:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696229.2240] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:23:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696229.2242] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul  1 18:23:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <warn>  [1656696229.2244] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open'
Jul  1 18:23:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696229.2246] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:23:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696229.2898] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:23:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696229.2898] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:24:04 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696244.1335] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706" name="MyOpenNetwork Open" pid=2091 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul  1 18:29:59 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656696599.5657] agent-manager: agent[908bac9042661364,:1.47/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.5328] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' (a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706)
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.5329] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706" name="MyOpenNetwork Open" pid=2091 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.5330] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.5333] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.5338] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.5340] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.6108] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyOpenNetwork Open'
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.6108] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.6108] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jul  1 18:36:49 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697009.6109] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Jul  1 18:36:50 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697010.6181] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:36:50 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697010.6182] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:37:15 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <warn>  [1656697035.2253] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul  1 18:37:15 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697035.2253] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:37:15 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697035.2257] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul  1 18:37:15 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <warn>  [1656697035.2261] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open'
Jul  1 18:37:15 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697035.2264] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:37:15 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697035.2302] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:37:15 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697035.2303] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3007] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' (a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706)
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3008] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="a85db91b-fb71-4e1d-a5f8-4b47fbaa1706" name="MyOpenNetwork Open" pid=2091 uid=1000 result="success"
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3010] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3019] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3037] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3045] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MyOpenNetwork Open' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3046] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyOpenNetwork Open'
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3047] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3047] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.3047] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.7526] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:37:37 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <info>  [1656697057.7528] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul  1 18:38:02 ron-370ST NetworkManager[570]: <warn>  [1656697082.2254] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` If it shows a kernel module in use, then add: `sudo dmesg | grep <module_you_found>` Perhaps it will be: `sudo dmesg | grep rtl8723ae` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks foryour help @chili555 I have made the edits you requested.

Comment: Let's also see: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: Hi @chili555 I updated it again, thank you.

Comment: We see nothing wrong and therefore potentially fixable so far. Let's see: `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep Network` As the result will probably be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Hi @chili555 here is the syslog: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5B4MRBzBWk/

Comment: @chili555 I can say that on this windows laptop I have had no issues connecting whatsoever. 'MyNetwork Open' just appears in the list af available networks and I select Connect. I take your point that nothing seems wrong so far (I didn't know exactly how to confirm which driver I had (so thank you), then if the driver I had installed functioned well) so I wonder what could be up. hopefully syslog will shed some light on this. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Is the result the same with the ethernet disconnected? I notice this in the log: *reason 'ssid-not-found'* Did the access point suddenly change? Is the router set to auto channel select or a fixed (recommended) channel? Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723

Comment: I don't have access to the wireless AP. The ubuntu laptop has never had an ethernet cable connected to it. I am writing this on a windows laptop that connects to the wireless network without issue. It is v. possible the 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz networks are named the same. If this is problematic for ubuntu (and the other linux distributions I have tried and failed to use over the last few days then that is really a bit of an indictment of linux generally! Wifi has to work in 2022. Anyway, if you think of anything else please let me know, but I guess I will have to reinstall windows lol. @chili555

Comment: An anecdotal case can't be construed as an indictment of Linux generally. The vast majority of Linux users' wireless, including mine, work perfectly. Please try: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8723ae` and then: `sudo modprobe rtl8723ae swenc=1` Any improvement?

Comment: I know my case shouldn't be construed as an indictment of linux generally, and I do appreciate your trying to help me, but there are a lot of people reporting the same kinds of issues over a long period of time, and all is as it should be with my installation, but just not working. It has taken me days of experimentation to actuallly establish. I tried your latest suggestions again, unfortunately without luck. Thanks for your help @chili555