# Atheros AR242x / AR542x Slow internet speed on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros, ath5k

I am getting slow internet speed on my Compaq Presario CQ61 laptop. There is a dedicated wifi/Bluetooth button. When this button is turned off, it starts to blink also.

speedtest-cli --share:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Kings Broadband (Kochi) [54.49 km]: 88.665 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 8.77 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 3.29 Mbit/s
```

uname -a:

```
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-122-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 15:00:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [103c:137b]
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k
    Kernel modules: ath5k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
```

lsmod | grep -e wmi:

```
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    32768  3 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
```

dmesg | grep AR2:

```
[   23.392522] ath5k: phy0: Atheros AR2425 chip found (MAC: 0xe2, PHY: 0x70)
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 03f0:171d HP, Inc Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**Update:**

I found that the systemd-networkd-wait-online service has failed to start. I tried to restart the service but not starting. **Is this the reason for my slow internet??**

sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online.service:

```
● systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-07-17 15:26:26 IST; 24min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
   Main PID: 393 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 17 15:24:25 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Jul 17 15:24:33 ubuntu systemd-networkd-wait-online[393]: managing: wlp2s0
Jul 17 15:26:26 ubuntu systemd-networkd-wait-online[393]: Event loop failed: Connection timed out
Jul 17 15:26:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 17 15:26:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 17 15:26:26 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
```

Why their is four entries in the Rfkill list?

rfkill list all:

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What average speed are you expecting?

Comment: @ChanganAuto If I connect via ethernet I am getting a speed of 80 to 90 Mbit/s. I am expecting the same speed.

Comment: ***I am expecting the same speed* but you shouldn't!**  Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x is a very old chip 802.11bg only! Since many years ago the bare minimum standard is 802.11n (Google to know the differences). Your WiFi device is not only inherently slow it may also slow down everything else connected to the same WiFi but it won't affect Ethernet. With an high degree of confidence I can say **your results are within the ballpark that can be realistically expected from such hardware**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Keeps Dropping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping)

Comment: @ChanganAuto Maybe that is the case. How to know the maximum speed of my wifi hardware? Also, I have updated the thread with some more information. See if it's relevant to this problem??

Comment: @waltinator No. I believe something wrong with the wifi driver itself.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS Maximum theoretical speed of you device is ~27Mb/s. But it is not reachable in practice especially if you have neighbors. All is OK with your device.