# Ubuntu 20.04 - WiFi signal strength keeps oscillating and dropping on 2.4GHz network

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, iwlwifi

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a pretty old laptop, with a wireless network card which doesn't support 5GHz WiFi. This has never caused me trouble, except for this specific network.

From time to time (maybe once in a few minutes or so) the WiFi signal strength (according to the system tray icon) starts to oscillate very fast, often dropping to zero. It disconnects quite rarely, prompting for some reason the network password, but in any case during the process the access to internet is really unstable.

Other devices are not affected, both when connected to the 2.4 and 5 GHz networks. The access point is close, just in the same room where I usually work.

Where should I try to look to debug this issue? I have access to the access point configuration if something needs to be tweaked.

Comment: Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723

Comment: @chili555 actually I've been doing some testing since yesterday night and it seems that splitting 2.4 and 5GHz networks might have improved stability. If confirmed I'll edit. Still a bit confused though, I never had issues with other dual-band networks